# Finding the linear representation of an ARMA process

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations

I have the following $ARMA(2,2)$ process:

$X_t + 0.9X_{t-1} = Z_t + 1.3Z_{t-1}$

I'd like to write it in the form:

$X_t = \sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty\psi_iZ_{t-i}$

I just want to compute the first few values of $\psi_i$. After consulting some other resources I was able to set up the equation:

$(1 + 1.3B) = (1 + 0.9B)\Psi(B) = (1 + 0.9B)(\psi_0 + \psi_1B + \psi_2B^2 + \cdots)$

I don't know where to go from here on solving for any values of $\psi_i$. Any suggestions would be much appreciated (I think this may potentially be an algebra inquiry more so than a time series inquiry).

Comment: It doesn't look like this question has got much traction. Have you considered posting on http://quant.stackexchange.com/?